# Replacing space with newline at specified positions in a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

InputFile:

```
filed1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12
```

I need to replace only the spaces after field3,field6,field9 to a new line character.
I tried the below sed command and it worked, But am looking for a more optimised solution for the same in order to handle input files with more fields.

```
sed -e 's/ /\
/3' -e 's/ /\
/6' -e 's/ /\
/9' InputFile
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you post the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i%3?FS:RS)}' file
filed1 field2 field3
field4 field5 field6
field7 field8 field9
field10 field11 field12
```

PS this does not stop at 3,6,9 but goes on (12,15,18...)

`for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)` Loop trough the line by one and one field.
`printf` print data `$i` print current data.  `i%3?FS:RS` if filed is number 3 use newline `RS`, else use field separator `FS`

Comment: This works perfect :) Can you please explain the logic behind the code?

Answer (score 2):

using `grep`

```
 echo "filed1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12" | grep -oE '([^ ]+ *){3}'
```

will produce output as

```
filed1 field2 field3
field4 field5 field6
field7 field8 field9
field10 field11 field12
```

using `sed`

```
 echo "filed1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12" | sed -r  's/(([^ ]+ *){3})/\1\n/g'
```

will produce output as

```
filed1 field2 field3
field4 field5 field6
field7 field8 field9
field10 field11 field12
```

`/(([^ ]+ *){3}` matches anything another than space followed by space `3` times which effectivly selects selects 3 fields.

```
 echo "filed1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12" | awk  '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}'
```

will give output as

```
filed1 field2 field3
field4 field5 field6
field7 field8 field9
field10 field11 field12
```

Throgh basic sed,

```
$ echo "filed1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12" | sed 's/\(\([^ ]\+ \)\{3\}\)/\1\n/g'
filed1 field2 field3 
field4 field5 field6 
field7 field8 field9 
field10 field11 field12
```

Comment: egrep is depreciated use this `grep -oE '([^ ]+ *){3}'` instead of that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj corrected :) i would eventually learn a lot from you :)

Comment: Both egrep -o / sed -r options are not supported in my unix server. Is it possible to achieve the same using awk?

Comment: @Sadhun what about `awk`?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Nothing specific about awk. Since grep -o and sed -r were not supported in server i would like to achieve the same in any other means

Comment: @nu11p01n73R In awk solution, Is it possible to minimize this piece of code - $i, $(i+1), $(i+2). Because i to need sepearte for 14 fields and even more. In those cases i need write from $i ... $(i+13)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(\([^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}\)\{2\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}/\1\
/g' YourFile
```

replace space after a group of 2 group of (non space + space) than 1 non space by a new line, and this repeated until it's possible on the line.

Posix version so `--posix` for GNU sed

```
sed 's/(([^ ]+ +){2}([^ ]+) +/\1\n/g' YourFile
```

should work on GNU sed (cannot test from here)

```
sed 's/\( *[^ ]*\)\{3\} */\1\
/g' YourFile
```

should also work on sed (depend on implementation)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ /\n/3;P;D' file
```

This changes the third space to a newline then prints and deletes upto and including the newline and repeats the process till the line is consumed.